# remove xmlns attribute from xml in wcf restful response

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wcf-rest

hi i am a beginner in WCF  ,

In WCF webservice using POST method with request format JSON, requirement is how to return a success result in plain XML like...

```
<result><respcode>err000</respcode><respmsg>success</respmsg></result>
```

If create XML in string and return in function the result showing below.

```
<result><respcode>err000<\/respcode><respmsg>success<\/respmsg><\/result>
```

I have added datacontract and return result in response the result comes with below xml tag.

```
<result xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/pacehfcltvr" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<respcode>err000</respcode>
<respmsg>success</respmsg>
</result>
```

Is there any way to remove xmlns="http://....... and get`<result>...</result>` only or how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
```

or

```
[WebService(Namespace = "")]
```